# Can you run Altiverb7XL as anything but stereo in SoundMiner?

Tags: altiverb, soundminer, 5.1, surround-sound, stereo-to-surround

I'm using SoundMiner 4.3pro v88 and recently upgraded to Altiverb7 XL

Can't seem to get it to run in quad \ 5.1 when using Soundminer

Can it be done??

Thanks
J

Comment: This is such a specific, technical question that it may be best to get in touch with te SM boys.

Comment: Yeah just awaiting a reply but working the weekend and keen for a solution..! Thanks 